# python program shows errors in arranging element of list in sorted order

Tags: python, sorting

I wrote this program to join all the elements of sub-lists in a single result empty list and then sort the returned result list. But after i run this program i get a unusual output. I get `None` on console screen.
What's wrong here in this code?

```
n=[[44,45,76,8,678,24,24],[45,45737,45,7373]]

def makelist(lis):
     result= []
     for i in lis:
         for j in i:
           result.append(j)
     return result

print makelist(n).sort()
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct here? It looks like you should indent the inner loop

Comment: sorry edited that was typing problem @EdChum

Comment: If you changed your last line to `n = makelist(n)
n.sort()
print n` it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n=[[44,45,76,8,678,24,24],[45,45737,45,7373]]

def makelist(lis):
 result= []
 for i in lis:
     for j in i:
       result.append(j)
 return result
```

All this is OK. Now run:

```
y = makelist(n)
y.sort()
print y
```

Your list is sorted and stored in the 'y' variable.

Answer (score 2):

`makelist(n).sort()` does not return anything

Do it like

```
temp = makelist(n)
temp.sort()
print temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a list lst and then calling sort will sort the list in-place, but it wiil not return the sorted list.

An example solution:

```
# Make this work in Python2 and Python3
from __future__ import print_function

import itertools


n=[[44,45,76,8,678,24,24],[45,45737,45,7373]]

def makelist(lis):
     result= []
     for i in lis:
         for j in i:
           result.append(j)
     return result

# Variation 1
print(sorted(makelist(n)))

# Variation 2
lst = makelist(n)
lst.sort()
print(lst)

# Variation 3 (replacing the makelist flattening operation)
lst = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(n))
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: can you explain you code? What is this future? makelist()  itertools.chain.from_iteratable(n)? This code really looks typical to me

Comment: The line with __future__ turns print into a funktion also in Python2.  It enables the code to run in both version 2 and 3.

Comment: The module itertools is a handy standard library and `chain.from_iterable(iterable)` (returns a `chain objekt`.
It is an alternate `chain()` contructor taking a single iterable argument that evaluates lazily.  When this is passed to `list` a new and flattended list is created replacing your `makelist` function.

Comment: So in summary, Variation 1 and 2 solves your problem and Variation 3 solves it in a different way and the `__future__` line makes it reasonably version agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Use sorted method instead of sort and this will fix your problem:

```
n=[[44,45,76,8,678,24,24],[45,45737,45,7373]]

def makelist(lis):
     result= []
     for i in lis:
         for j in i:
           result.append(j)
     return result

print sorted(makelist(n))

# OR check this way
res = makelist(n)
print res
res.sort()
print res
```

To read more about sort() you can use the following link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_sort.htm

Answer (score 1):

sort() is a method of list. It sorts the list in place and does not return the list as a reminder of that fact.

sorted() is a builtin function, not a method on list, because it's
more general taking any iterator as its first argument, not just a list.  It of course does return a list.

```
n=[[44,45,76,8,678,24,24],[45,45737,45,7373]]

    def makelist(lis):
         result= []
         for i in lis:
             for j in i:
               result.append(j)
         return result
    print sorted(makelist(n))
```

The .sort() method of lists sorts the list in place, while sorted() creates a new list.

Answer (score 1):

sort() function sorts in-place and returns None. On the other hand, sorted() function returns a new list. Thus, you can use your current implementation:

```
makelist(n).sort()
print(n)
```

Or, you can use sorted():

```
print sorted(makelist(n), key=int)
```